# Update pathauto alias without node_load?

Tags: path-aliases, uri

I want to force an update of the URL alias without loading the node.

Can this be done? If not, any lighter ways to update a [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not without circumventing the pathauto module logic (e.g. altering the alias directly in the DB).

The main function that gets executed in pathauto node updates/inserts, [`pathauto_create_alias`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_create_alias/7), requires a parameter, `$data`, passed to it. In a node context, `$data` is the node object. Without this node object data, pathauto would not be able retrieve data needed for tokens pattens (e.g. `[node:title]`).